# Python Connect 4 Horizontal win

Tags: python

So Basically I am, trying to code the horizontal win condition for a connect 4 Game In python I figured out the way to do this for 4 Connecting Chips In python would be

```
for x in range(cols - 3):
    for y in range(rows):
if board[x][y] == color and board[x+1][y] == color and board[x+2][y] ==color and   board[x+3]==color:    
            return True
```

But The Problem is I need something similar to this to  work a winning connecting chips as determined by the user it could be four or what ever amount the user wants.

```
for x in range(col - 3):
  for y in range(row):
        for z in range (0, required_connected_chips):
                 if board_values[x + z][y] == color:
```

required _Connecting_chips is the winning connecting chips as determined by the user after writing this i am basically stuck on what to do next and would take any suggestions or feedback on how to solve my problem and i am sorry if i got my indentation wrong on some of the code.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a boolean to save the output of `board_values[x + z][y] == color:`. If this keeps True until the end of your loop return True. Like:

```
b = True
for z in range (0, required_connected_chips):
    b &= board_values[x + z][y] == color
if b:
    return True
```

Edit: for not checking every Field u might check b in the loops after setting it so it would look like:

```
b = True
for z in range (0, required_connected_chips):
    if not board_values[x + z][y] == color:
        b = False
        break
if b:
    return True
```

Edit2: removed redundant "&" in second code example

Edit3: changed the second code example a bit further to a way it feels bether for me

Comment: so i understand what you are saying but what does the & symbol next to b mean?

Comment: Its the bitwise AND operator, performing an operation like: b = b and board_values...   have a look here https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: I had used "&" sign in first Code since i did not cancel the loop there. If i had just overwritten b it might had happened on last run of the loop it would be overwritten with True, even if it had been set to False in a prior iteration. Since Second Code cancels when b is False it's not needed there anymore